# Use Clang LibTooling to scan C++ source that has call to local class in a templated parent class

Tags: c++, templates, clang, libtooling, local-class

Source code to scan:

```
template <typename T>
class HB {
    T m;
public:
    void HBfunc1();
};

template <typename T>
void HB<T>::HBfunc1() {  
    class HC {      
    public:
        void HCfunc2() { };
    };    
    HC().HCfunc2();
}

void TestTemplate() { HB<int>().HBfunc1(); };
```

The above code works fine in VS2019, when use Clang LibTooling to scan the AST:

```
virtual bool VisitCallExpr(CallExpr *call) {

    std::cout << "VisitCallExpr: ";
    if (call->getDirectCallee()) {
        std::cout << " "<<call->getDirectCallee()->getQualifiedNameAsString();
    }
    else {
        Decl *callee = call->getCalleeDecl();
        if (!callee) {
            std::cout << "\nNow dump call:\n";
            call->dump();
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
    return true;
}
```

When visiting the CallExpr for this line in the scaned source:

```
HC().HCfunc2();
```

The callee is null and the dump of the CallExpr are:

```
VisitCallExpr:
Now dump call:
CallExpr 0x1c2ef83b3a0 '<dependent type>'
`-CXXDependentScopeMemberExpr 0x1c2ef83b348 '<dependent type>' lvalue .HCfunc2
  `-CXXUnresolvedConstructExpr 0x1c2ef83b320 'class HC' 'class HC'
```

Clang doesn't report error in the scanning process (Since the code works fine).

In LLVM source code there is:

```
// This represents the type of an expression whose type is
// totally unknown, e.g. 'T::foo'.  It is permitted for this to
// appear in situations where the structure of the type is
// theoretically deducible.
BUILTIN_TYPE(Dependent, DependentTy)
```

Why the type HC is considered unknown? Will any type be unknown while scanning the AST without issueing any warning/erroe? How to visit invocation like this and extract information about its callee? Does the scaned code have problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang is being conservative in this case by marking the function call as **unresolved** (aka **dependent**). **Dependent** things appear only in templates. It means that some syntactic structure *might* depend on template parameters.

`HC` class is not a usual class, you will have as many separate `HC` classes, as the number of instantiations of `HB`. So, if `HC` does not use `T`, there is little to no sense to place it inside of `HBfunc1`. Otherwise, it is dependent indeed. Clang prefers to be safe and avoids making assumptions that smth is not **dependent** when it is defined in a **dependent context**.

Because of these reasons, it is *absolutely* normal to have AST nodes like this. It is not a parser error, everything worked as intended. As per exact information about the callee, short answer is - there is no way while analyzing the template. However, clang generates AST for every instantiation. Those have usual AST structure, and can be easily visited.

I hope this information is helpful!